# Find unused tty in the shell like bash?

Tags: bash, debian, tty

Is there a generic way to find unused `tty` in the shells like `bash`?

The following seem to work, but I suppose there must be a better way?

```
$ used=$({ find /proc/{0..9}*/fd/0 -printf '%l$\n' | grep tty;} 2> /dev/null)
$ unused=$(find /dev/ -name 'tty*' | grep -ve "$used")
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean Linux virtual terminals, there is the `VT_OPENQRY` `ioctl()` to get the *first* free virtual terminal (as used by `openvt` for instance), but you would need a file descriptor to a console device for that already. Alternatively, you could do (as root):

```
comm -23 <(printf '%s\n' /dev/tty[1-9]*) \
         <(lsof -Fn /dev/tty[1-9]* | sed -n 's/^n//p' | sort -u)
```

Which you could generalise to other types of tty devices like serial ones.

That would be more robust in that it would only consider those device paths and not have issues with filenames with regexp operators or newlines, but like in your approach, that would not work properly if the tty devices are open by any other path that the `/dev/ttyxx` ones.

Another approach would be to rely on device numbers instead of their *canonical* path.

With GNU `stat`:

```
find -L /proc/[1-9]*/fd/. ! -name . -prune -type c -exec  stat -Lc '%t %T' {} + |
  awk '$1 == "4" {seen[$2]}
       END {
         for (i=1; i<=63; i++)
           if (!(sprintf("%x", i) in seen))
             print "/dev/tty" i
       }'
```

Comment: Is it any better than my original method? I would also need to install `lsof`, which by the rule of thumb is not packaged along with many distributions.

Comment: @NarūnasK, `lsof` is packaged with all distributions and is often even installed by default. Also, if you wanted to use something like that outside of Linux, you couldn't use `/proc/*/fd`.

Comment: I have actually meant to say it is not included in the package list, which are installed by default, so for instance on Debian I have to install it separately, and to my best knowledge, I've always had.